# how to add values in arraylist with Switch case in JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a new with Java and I have a question. How to add values or index in arrayList in Switch case?

I have tried without switch case, it will work well, but in Switch case, not working at all!!. my code run but i cant add values for example in case 1.

here's my code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Eqla3tech {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        menu();

}

static void menu(){

    ArrayList<String> cars = new ArrayList<String>();
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Add Student <1>");
    System.out.println("remove Student <2>");
    System.out.println("show list of students <3>");
    System.out.println("how many students? <4>");
    int num = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    switch(num){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("write student name!!");


            cars.add(input.next());
            menu();
            break;

        case 2:
            System.out.println("what number of index of student to remove");
            int index = input.nextInt();
            cars.remove(index);
            menu();
            break;

        case 3:
            System.out.println("Here's a list you have added.");
           System.out.println(cars);
            menu();
            break;

        case 4:
            System.out.println("Here's haw many students");
            System.out.println(cars.size());
            menu();
            break;


    }
}
}
```

what i try to do is make arrays as dynamic and i can add or remove from Switch without losing values.

please apology for my bad English.

I have tried to make user enter input but not worked. I mean, eveytime user enter input, value dont save in add arrayList.

I think i am close but i lost too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `cars` list is local to one call of the method called `menu()`.

When you call that method again, it gets a different `cars` list.

You can solve this by using a loop inside a single call of the `menu()` method -- such as a `do-while` loop. Then each pass through the loop will use the same list.

Comment: I have tried as you told me and worked well with do-while and switch case. Thank you so much.